# LWC HTML title attribute showing bad value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, html, date

Hi need some help on the setting the title attribute dynamically of the date field in the lightning formatted date for my LWC value which is being get displayed on the screen from the incoming value from the JSON in HTML from Javascript, kindly help me out

Below is the sample JSON in the response: Sample JSON as below in Javascript:

```
sampledata = [
      {
       "accy":"testdgd",
       "cdate":"1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Y",
       "ldate":"1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Y",
       "rowKeyUni":"rowValUniA",
      },
      {
       "accy":"yutjdhfj",
       "cdate":"1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Y",
       "ldate":"1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Y",
       "rowKeyUni":"rowValUniB",
       },
      {
       "accy":"hgjfughjf",
       "cdate":"1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Y",
       "ldate":"1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Y",
       "rowKeyUni":"rowValUniC"
      }
    ]
```

I am iterating on the rowKeyUni and displaying the cdate and ldate in the HTML as shown below and displaying the data on the UI.

HTML Code for displaying data on UI

```
<tbody>
    <template for:each={sampledata} for:item='sampledataO'>
        <tr key={sampledata.rowKeyUni}>
           <template if:true={sampledata.cdate}>
              <lightning-formatted-date-time value={sampledataO.cdate}
                title={sampledataO.cdate} year='numeric' month='numeric' day='numeric' time-zone='UTC'>
    </lightning-formatted-date-time>
</template>
```

Issue Facing: date on the uI is correctly getting displayed as 13/09/1998 ....but when user put the cursor over it then it display the value from the JSON as it is without any formatting it as :-- 1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Y is there any way to fix this with the help of javascript

Answer (score 0):

If `"1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Y"` is in UTC and you want to display the date in local time, use something like this:

```js
let myDate = new Date("1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Z");
// A function for padding an integer with a leading zero if it's 1 digit
const pad = (num) => {
  let s = "0" + num;
  return s.substr(s.length - 2);
}
let ddMmYyyy = 
  pad(myDate.getDate()) + 
  "/" + 
  // getMonth() returns the zero index-based month, so add 1
  pad(myDate.getMonth() + 1) +
  "/" + 
  myDate.getFullYear();
console.log(ddMmYyyy);
// Output: 13/09/1998, unless the user is in a -8 or more time zone 
// (e.g. Pacific Standard Time), in which case the output is 12/09/1998
```

If you want to always get the literal date portion of `"1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Z"`, i.e. you never want that value to be translated into a user's local time zone, use this instead:

```js
let myDate = new Date("1998-09-13T07:34:37.577Z");
const pad = (num) => {
  let s = "0" + num;
  return s.substr(s.length - 2);
}
let ddMmYyyy = 
  pad(myDate.getUTCDate()) + 
  "/" + 
  pad(myDate.getUTCMonth() + 1) + 
  "/" + 
  myDate.getUTCFullYear();
console.log(ddMmYyyy);
// Output: 13/09/1998
```

### Reference

- On date formatting in JavaScript:
  https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-format-date-javascript/
- On padding integers with zeros: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998784/how-to-output-numbers-with-leading-zeros-in-javascript

Comment: @mathew Souther this is too complicated to change the title attribute.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I think it's the only way you're going to achieve what you're asking for.